# REGEX pattern creation

Tags: regex

I need a regex expression that allows single alphabet or numbers separated by commas like `1,2,3` or `A,B,C` AND single alpha or numeric LIKE `A C 1 2`. It should not allow `123 abc` or `ABC`.

I tried `^(?:([A-Z0-9a-z])(?!.?\1),)[A-Z0-9a-z]$` but it doesn't work.

Comment: Can you provide more details than "it doesn't work"?

Comment: It seems to allow continuous alpha numeric strings as well eg ABCD,1234

Comment: I think `^[A-Z0-9a-z](?=([ ,])|$)(?:\1[A-Z0-9a-z])*$` will work, see https://regex101.com/r/rMeq4F/1

Comment: If one of the answers below solves your problem please consider accepting it.

Answer (score 0):

I think this would work. I'm keeping the ^ and $ to be consistent with your example.
My best understanding of your question leads me to the following specific requirements - this is what I believe you're getting at, but if not then we need to get more clear with the question setup and context:

1. When comma is the delimiter, you specifically used all-numbers or all-letters in the example. Whereas, when space is the delimiter, you used a mix of letters and numbers.
2. I took this as an intentional communication, and therefore this leads to a requirement that IF delimiter is comma, then only one type of main character is allowed throughout the whole string - all letters or all numbers.
3. Whereas if the delimiter is space, then a mix of letters and numbers is allowed
4. This kind of requirement is therefore going to require multiple patterns with a vertical-line "or" operator

`^([A-Za-z](,[A-Za-z])*)|([0-9](,[0-9])*)|([A-Z0-9a-z]( [A-Z0-9a-z])*)$`

There are 3 major pieces there, separated by vertical line operators. In plain language they could be expressed as:

1. The entire string can be one or more alpha chars, separated by single commas, OR
2. The entire string can be one or more numbers, separated by single commas, OR
3. The entire string can be one or more letters-or-numbers, separated by single space characters (all alpha, all number, and mix are all allowed).

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to mix and match the space and the comma's (So `1 2,3`
`A C 1,2` are not valid) you can use a capture group with a backreference:

```
^[A-Za-z0-9](?:([ ,])[A-Za-z0-9](?:\1[A-Za-z0-9])*)?$
```

**Explanation**

- `^` Start of string
- `[A-Za-z0-9]` Match a single char [A-Za-z0-9]
- `(?:` Non capture group

  - `([ ,])` Capture group 1, match either a space or `,`
  - `[A-Za-z0-9]` Match a single char [A-Za-z0-9]
  - `(?:\1[A-Za-z0-9])*` OPptionally repeat matching what is captured in group 1 followed by a single char [A-Za-z0-9]
- `)?` Close the outer on capture group and make it optional
- `$` End of string

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/33gBGA/1)